# OrderBy list for only Date but not Time

Tags: c#, linq

I have `IList<customClass>`

My `CustomClass: CreatedDate(DateTime), Name(string), Number(int)`

I use `OrderBy(p => p.CreatedDate)`

My question: how do I custom or find a way to order CreatedDate just only Date, not include Time when order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that `CreatedDate` is of type `DateTime` you can do the following.

```
OrderBy(p => p.CreatedDate.Date)
```

Comment: FYI...'The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'